# Set texture wrap option in kivy language

Tags: python, kivy

Is it possible to set texture wrap option in kv file? For an example,

```
Rectangle:
    source: "texture.png"
    pos: root.pos
```

will create textured Rectangle, however, if the rectangle gets resized, texture will wrap and distort instead of repeating.

I could always create texture separately in python code and change it there, but this is preferred option, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's currently a convenient way to do this in kv alone. It's been a minor missing feature for a while.

You can make the Rectangle in kv and access it via the canvas, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's what I thought. Thank you very much, one thing more though. How can I access the rectangle via the canvas?